# Finding roots of a mathematical equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, roots

If $x^3 + 3^x = 0$ what will be the value of $x$?
what will be the easiest way to find it mathematically?

Answer (score 3):

Put

$$f(x)=x^3+3^x\implies f'(x)=3x^2+3^x\log3>0\implies f(x)\;\;\text{is monotonic ascending}$$

so $\;f(x)=0\;$ has at most one single solution.

Now, we have that $\;f(-1)\cdot f(0)=\left(-\frac43\right)\cdot1<0\;\implies$
 *the* zero of $\;f(x)\;$ is in $\;(-1,0)\;$ . You any want to continue with bisecting this interval or use any other numerical method (Newton, Rapson-Newton, Lambert Function, etc.) to approximate it.

Comment: Hey, Is there a way to proceed using this below : $x^3+3^x=0 \\
\implies x^3=-3^x\\
\implies 3\log x=-x\log 3 \\
\implies \frac{\log x}{x}=-\frac{\log 3}{3}$ ?

Comment: @MonK I guess so, yet that still is a transcendental equation which, most probably, will require some approximation...

Comment: @MonK. Take care : $\log(-3^x)\neq -x\log(3)$. If you want to do it that way, define $x=-y$ first.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would solve this numerically, using e.g. [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

However it can be solved exactly in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$x=\frac{-3W\left(\frac{\log(3)}{3}\right)}{\log(3)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3 + 3^x = 0 \iff x^3 = -3^x$$

If $x$ is real, $$\implies x = -3^{\frac{x}{3}} \implies3 ^{-\frac{x}{3}} x = -1 \implies xe^{-\frac{x}{3} \ln3} = -1 \implies -\frac{x}{3} \ln(3) e^{-\frac{x}{3} \ln3} = \frac{\ln 3}{3}$$

So $$-\frac{x}{3} \ln 3 = W(\frac{\ln 3}{3})$$

$$x = - \frac{3W(\frac{\ln 3}{3})}{\ln 3 }$$

If x is complex, $$x = -3^{\frac{x}{3}} \omega $$ or $$x = -3^{\frac{x}{3}} \omega^2 $$ where $\omega$ is a primitive root of order $3$.

In the same way, one will get $$x = - \frac{3W(-\frac{1}{6} i (-i \ln 3 + \sqrt 3 \ln 3 ))}{\ln 3 }$$ and $$x = - \frac{3W(\frac{1}{6} i (i \ln 3 + \sqrt 3 \ln 3 ))}{\ln 3 }$$

Where W is [Lambert W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) and $i$ is unity of imaginery.